# Render span tag with title attribute with ASP.NET MVC 3 Helpers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

It's possible to add a HTML `title` attribute to an input tag like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { title = "Customer name" })
```

Is there a similar helper for static text? With `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)` I can render the text from a model property. How can I add HTML attributes so that I get a `span` tag rendered like this:

```
<span title="Customer name">ABC</span>
```

Comment: This question's explicitly tagged "MVC **3**", but note that for version 4 (razor 2) and up you can just get away with doing e.g. `<span title="@Model.NameTooltip">@Model.Name</span>`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Custom html helper is probably the neatest solution.

```
public static MvcHtmlString SpanFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var valueGetter = expression.Compile();
    var value = valueGetter(helper.ViewData.Model);

    var span = new TagBuilder("span");
    span.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    if (value != null)
    {
        span.SetInnerText(value.ToString());
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(span.ToString());
}
```

=>

```
@Html.SpanFor(model => model.Name, new { title = "Customer name" })
```

Comment: That works great! I only had to catch that `value` can be `null` (`if (value != null)` before `span.SetInnerText(value.ToString());` Thank you very much!

Comment: data binded to this spanfor is not available during httpPost... Any update for that

Comment: I had issues with this for data attributes, you need to wrap htmlAttributes with     HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes) otherwise it doesn't replace _ with - like other objects.

Answer (score 5):

```
<span title="Customer name">@Model.Name</span>
```

Comment: or `<span title="Customer name">@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Name)</span>` if `Name` can be `null`

Comment: So, is there no built-in helper which could create this span tag?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using @HTML.DisplayFor(model=>model.CustomerName) It will render as text, It will not shows any tag inside the values.

If you want to bind the "DisplayFor" using span , Use the below tag,

```
<span id="CustomerName">@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.CustomerName)</span>
```

Comment: This solution allowed me to continue to use the display template for my datetime value that @Html.DisplayFor uses as well as add a title to the span.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but works ;-) (required field, without rendering .EditorFor content get lost during submit, even HTML comment around does not work, tested on **System.Web.Mvc 5.0.0.0**)

```
<b style="display:none">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)</b>
<input name="UserName" disabled readonly value=@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.UserName)>
```

Original looked like:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The User Name field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="Hate Razor !">
```

Answer (score -1):

You use the below

```
<span title="Customer name">@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.CustomerName)</span>
```

Comment: This doesn't create a span tag.