# Form Input Syntax In RAZOR

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this code

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputName" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
</div>
```

how can I apply same span class to below line of code in razor?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name,
                      new {
                            @class = "form-control",
                            @placeholder="Enter Name",
                            @requried="required"
                          }
                 )
```

Help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do it

```
<div class="form-group">
@*label if you have any*@
  <div class="input-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name,new {@class = "form-control",@placeholder="EnterName",@requried="required"})
   <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
 <div class="input-group">
                              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName,
                              new
                              {
                                  @class = "form-control",
                                  @placeholder = "Enter Name",
                                  @requried = "required"
                              }

                         )
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk">  </span></span>
</div>
```

Custom html helper is probably give a solution.

Check [How can I override the @Html.LabelFor template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196290/how-can-i-override-the-html-labelfor-template)

and

[Render span tag with title attribute with ASP.NET MVC 3 Helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001411/render-span-tag-with-title-attribute-with-asp-net-mvc-3-helpers)

Comment: it was close enough , but the glyphicon-asterisk wasn't aligned properley. Thank You for hlep